# Error returned by Nuance DragonMobile text-to-speech when maximum number of transactions is reached

Tags: objective-c, ios, speech

I'm about to release my App on IOS that uses Nuance Dragon Mobile SDK. I'm signed up for the "Silver" plan, which allows me 20 transactions per day.

My question is, does anyone know what error is returned by Nuance, when the limit is exceeded? I'm concerned, because I am filtering out:

```
error.code == 5 // Because this fires whenever I interrupt running speech
error.code == 1 // Because after interrupting speech, the first time I restart, it cuts off
            // before finished, so I automatically start again, so as not to trouble the user to do so
```

I figure if Nuance returns an error different from these, I'll allow it to pass through, and be able to alert the user that they've reached their daily limit.

I think the following gives the possible errors:

```
extern NSString * const SKSpeechErrorDomain;

enum {
    SKServerConnectionError = 1,
    SKServerRetryError = 2,
    SKRecognizerError = 3,
    SKVocalizerError = 4,
SKCancelledError = 5,
};
```

It seems likely to me that it's the SKServerConnectionError that would be fired. In that case, I need to come up with a different strategy. If I could figure out what's going on with the restart issue I wouldn't have to filter out that error. Plus, when I automatically restart these false starts, I'm probably racking up my transaction count, which is unfortunate.

Anybody have experience with this aspect of the Nuance SDK for IOS?

Comment: from the looks of the code AND their docs, Id strongly vote for ServerConnectionError

Comment: You're probably right. This means I have to figure solve the restart issue, ie doing a     **[vocalizer speakString:message];** right after a  **[vocalizer cancel]** always results in the speech being truncated, so I have to re-launch the **[vocalizer speakString:message];** If I solve that, I don't have to filter out instances of server error.